# SDL vs SFML using C when portability matters most?

Tags: c, opengl, cross-platform, sdl, sfml

I have been doing a lot of reading on SDL and SFML, and no doubt have missed some information or am not understanding it. Here is what I have gleaned:

- SDL is presently the standard (most popular)
- SDL uses C and software rendering (which is slow?)
- SDL embeds on everything?

- SFML is becoming more popular
- SFML uses C++ (but has C bindings) and utilizes hardware accelerated rendering (fast)
- SFML won't embed on everything?

I have to use C and OpenGL for what I want to do. I also need to make sure that the program is as portable as possible. It cannot be slow however.

What should I do?

Comment: If you use OpenGL with SDL, it's not using software rendering unless there is a problem with your drivers.

Comment: Here are my sources that would suggest otherwise:
http://www.gpwiki.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=129157#p129157

and

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/24975/#msg132778

Both suggest that at least 2D rendering is based on software and not hardware.

Comment: If you're using purely OpenGL for 2D, that's nonsense. Either way it will be hardware unless your drivers are broken. If you're using non-OpenGL SDL functions for 2D though, that certainly could be software.

Comment: @R.. Using OpenGl for 2D has sense. It is possible to use the 3D pipeline to render flat primitive - that will allow you to be benefit the hardware acceleration and all its sweet features. Rendering 2D with the CPU has non-sense.

Comment: Sorry my comment was grammatically ambiguous. I was pointing out that the claim that "2D rendering is based on software" with SDL is nonsense if you're talking about OpenGL-based 2D rendering. I never intended to say you shouldn't use OpenGL for 2D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using OpenGl with SDL, rendering is done by the hardware, not in software. I never tried SFML, but SDL is very simple and it is a mature library. Having wrote some OpenGl with SDL, the only problem I faced is that it is not possible to have multiple windows with SDL. Regarding portability, my program worked on Linux, MacOS and Windows. For the moment, I don't have any reason to switch to another library.

Comment: SDL1.3 enables multiple windows, AFAIK.

Comment: Using SDL + OpenGL is quite easy, and elegant. I have a tutorial setup here if interested: http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-opengl-tutorial-basics/

Answer (score 5):

**[SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/features.php)** is a more mature library. It works well, probably even better than SDL on Windows, Linux, Mac OS:

> SFML compiles on standard platforms like Windows (98, 2000, XP, Vista) and Unix systems (Linux, Mac OS X). As the library grows up, support for more operating systems will be added.

Also, SFML has been supporting hardware acceleration from the start, whereas with SDL there are some doubts about that.

However, SDL works on more platforms right now, including mobile ones.

And using C language you may not benefit from all the object-oriented goodness of SFML.

So you should use SDL with C (or for mobile platforms) and SFML with C++.

---

#### So you want to do 2D stuff? Don't break your head with OpenGL, just use SFML! It uses OpenGL and hardware acceleration internally for 2D.

Comment: +1 if portable means for OSX, Windows classic (not Windows Store) and Linux. SFML has a portable architecture, but does not have support for Android, iOS etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say that you have to use C I would suggest you go with SDL. When using OpenGL with SDL it will be hardware accelerated. Only the SDL 2D graphics functions will be in software but since you use OpenGL you won't use them to draw anything on the screen.

SDL is pretty portable and SDL 1.3 (from svn or archive on the homepage) can also be compiled for Android where you use OpenGL ES.